# Excel file download failed in Chrome using php yii2

Tags: php, html, excel, yii2

```
<a href="/Files/file.xxxx" download class="btn btn-success">Download File</a>
```

I have a page in which I have a download button that should download the file. But it failed to download. I have checked this issue but didn't find any solution.

[image]

In above picture it shows that there is not file.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have wrong extension "file.xxxx", can you change it to exact file path and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From **[google chrome help center](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2898334?hl=en)**

> If you try to download a file and it doesn’t work, first try to fix the error with these troubleshooting steps:
>
> 1. Make sure your internet connection is working normally. If your internet connection is unstable, learn how to fix internet stability issues.
>
>    . Chrome will automatically resume the download. You can also resume the file download by clicking the Down arrow Down Arrow and then Resume or More More and then Resume.
> 2. Try to download the file later.
> 3. Contact the website owner.

If 1 and 2 not work. and you trying with other browsers then the problem is in your file and server.

You can fix it by checking [file_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) and send file by [Yii2 sendFile](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-response#sendFile()-detail). see example:

```
$file_path = '/route/to/path/file.xlsx';
if (file_exists($file_path)) {
    return Yii::$app->response->sendFile($file_path);
}else{
    return 'file not found';
}
```

you can use this code in any **controller** .

Comment: Hi, Sorry for excepting too late but it does solves my issue

Comment: Can you please look into one of my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64906846/6854117) that is related to the path ?