# Download an excel file HTML

Tags: html

I keep getting a 404 error saying the file is not on the web server, trying to create an href link to download an excel file.

```
<p><a href="/ExcelFile.xlsx" download> Click to Download </a></p>
```

The excel file is in the same directory as the page this is being worked on currently, so there is no file path, I have tried a file path but it gives the same error.

Comment: Try removing the leading `/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a download-link to an Excel file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8752698/how-to-create-a-download-link-to-an-excel-file)

Comment: @prd removing the slash did not work. same thing.

Comment: Do you really mean '.xlxs'?

Comment: @MandyShaw thatd be a typo on my part in the question, xlsx

Comment: Your HTTP server could be configured to not allow requests for files with that extension. There's no way for us to help you given the information you've provided thus far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had to add a folder for files and it worked.

Original:

```
<p><a href="/ExcelFile.xlsx" download> Click to Download </a></p>
```

Working:

```
<p><a href="TestFile/ExcelFile.xlsx" download> Click to Download </a></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are saying that ExcelFile.xlxs is in the root folder of the web server / virtualhost.

So if you have a structure where /www is your top level folder, than ExcelFile.xlxs need to be directly in /www and not in a subfolder.

Take a look at absolute and relative paths, this will explain this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a `Downloads` directory under `webapp` directory.

```
webapp -> Downloads -> all the downloadable files
```

Afterwards you may use the below `code` to download into your machine once the link is clicked.

```
<p>Info: Please Download File 
   <a href="Downloads/Template.xlsx" download>Download File</a>
</p>
```

Note: you can add target="_blank" to the download link via a new window.

```
<p>Info: Please Download File 
   <a href="Downloads/Template.xlsx" target="_blank">Download File via New Window</a>
</p>
```